# SQL - Why does the ordering matter for this select?

Tags: sql, select

I ran the below code and got the following error;

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.5' to data type int

```
BEGIN -- first update to check Interface held SMR and Interface held SMA
update interface set INTERR = 'U7'
from interface i
where 
i.conttype = 'SMR' 
and isnumeric(i.contrate)=1 
and cast(i.contrate as decimal(12,2)) < 5 
and caseno = @caseno
and exists (
    select 1 
    from interface i2 
    where i2.caseno = @caseno 
    and i2.conttype = 'SMA' 
    and i2.intmembno = i.intmembno 
    and i2.effdte = i.effdte 
    and i2.contrate > cast(0 as decimal(12,2)) 
    and isnumeric(i2.contrate)=1
)
```

In this example SMR = 5 and SMA = 1.5 and both values have been declared as Numerics. However by switching around the ordering of the clauses the error stops occuring and the stored procedure continues on as it should (see below)

```
BEGIN -- first update to check Interface held SMR and Interface held SMA
update interface set INTERR = 'U7'
from interface i
where 
i.conttype = 'SMR' 
and isnumeric(i.contrate)=1 
and cast(i.contrate as decimal(12,2)) < 5 
and caseno = @caseno
and exists (
    select 1 
    from interface i2 
    where i2.caseno = @caseno 
    and isnumeric(i2.contrate)=1 -- This was moved up
    and i2.conttype = 'SMA' 
    and i2.intmembno = i.intmembno 
    and i2.effdte = i.effdte 
    and i2.contrate > cast(0 as decimal(12,2))
)
```

Can you help me understand why the ordering matters? Normally it doesn't and shouldn't, as far as I know.

Thanks! 
Paul

Comment: I would guess short-cut evaluation: when having a lot of and-conditions, when one fails, the next doesn't even get evaluated. Thus, in your 2nd example, isnumeric(i2.contrate)=1 will fail , and the i2.contrate>cast will not get evaluated, so everything's ok. But, if the > is evaluated first, it tries to cast it without success, and thus you get the error.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? That is a non-standard UPDATE statement.

Comment: As far as I know, you are correct that the order of the conditions in the where clause should not effect the order they are evaluated by the database.
My guess is that once you've changed the order, you forced your database to create a new execution plan, and it's only by luck the conditions where evaluated in such an order that the error didn't occur.

Comment: I'm guessing SQL Server based on syntax and the error message.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, I've been informed repeatedly that order doesn't matter, so whilst your logic makes sense... it goes counter to common knowledge

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes this is T-SQL server. A victory by luck is one I'll take, even though I'm not sure why it's occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` conditions are not executed in any particular order.  This is even true when using subqueries and CTEs -- the optimizer rearranges processing and for good reason.

And, using implicit conversion is dangerous -- as you are finding.  So, use explicit conversions and do:

```
where i.conttype = 'SMR' and
      try_cast(i.contrate as decimal(12,2)) < 5 and
      caseno = @caseno and
      exists (select 1 
              from interface i2 
              where i2.caseno = @caseno and
                    i2.conttype = 'SMA' and
                    i2.intmembno = i.intmembno and
                    i2.effdte = i.effdte and
                    try_cast(i2.contrate as decimal(12,2)) > 0
             )
```

Notes:

- You do not have to check `isnumeric()`.
- There is no need to cast a constant such as `0` for the comparison.
- You can do similar things with a `case` in pre-2012 versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I have the extra contstraints for different erroneous values that could be entered, letters and symbols for example.
I did not know about try_cast though, that's a gem! Thanks

In this particular case, if ordering does not matter, then do you know why one way would work and one wouldnt?

Comment: @Kalaan . . . Luck.  The conditions might happen to occur in the right order, but you have no control over that.

Comment: I knew about the where clause, but always thought CTE's and derived tables should be evaluated before the queries using them...

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . If only SQL Server had an option to materialize CTEs . . .   The CTE logic is incorporated into the query directly.  It is not evaluated first.